# after updating v-calendar : error message: You may need an appropriate loader

Tags: vue.js, webpack, babeljs

I get this message after upgrading v-calendar to the latest version on my Vue project.

```
./node_modules/v-calendar/lib/v-calendar.umd.min.js
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:30468)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
```

and this is my code:

webpack.base.conf.js

```
 module: {
    rules: [
(...)
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        include: [resolve('src'), resolve('test'), resolve('node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client')]
      },
(...)
```

package.json:

```
{
(...)
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js",
    "start": "npm run dev",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue src",
    "build": "node build/build.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@chenfengyuan/vue-carousel": "^1.0.5",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "connect-history-api-fallback": "^1.6.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "query-string": "^6.2.0",
    "quill-image-drop-module": "^1.0.3",
    "quill-image-extend-module": "^1.1.2",
    "quill-image-resize-module": "^3.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "v-calendar": "^2.2.1",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
(...)
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.3.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.1",
    "babel-helper-vue-jsx-merge-props": "^2.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-jsx": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx": "^3.5.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.3.2",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.22.0",
    "chalk": "^2.0.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
    "eslint": "^4.15.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^10.2.1",
    "eslint-friendly-formatter": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^5.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^3.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^4.0.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.4",
    "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "^1.6.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "node-notifier": "^5.1.2",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "ora": "^1.2.0",
    "portfinder": "^1.0.13",
    "postcss-import": "^11.0.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.0.8",
    "postcss-url": "^7.2.1",
    "prerender-spa-plugin": "^3.4.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.0",
    "semver": "^5.3.0",
    "shelljs": "^0.7.6",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.1",
    "url-loader": "^1.1.2",
    "vue-loader": "^13.3.0",
    "vue-style-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.9.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.11.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ]
}
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["env", {
      "modules": false,
      "targets": {
        "browsers": ["> 1%", "last 2 versions", "not ie <= 8"]
      }
    }],
    "stage-2"
  ],
  "plugins": ["transform-vue-jsx", "transform-runtime"]
}
```

Webpack is so difficult for me...
This webpack settings in my project seems like old version but I don't know where to start to fix it. (I already tried but I had to change too many things and too many errors so I gave up.)
please kindly help if anyone knows the solution.

Comment: It is indeed old - you'd better switch to Vue-CLI v3.

Comment: Encountered the same problem and the official did not give any response https://github.com/nathanreyes/v-calendar/issues/683

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with a different package and it was solved by parsing the package.

In your webpack.base.conf.js add this `resolve('node_modules/v-calendar')` to your `include`

> webpack.base.conf.js

```
{
    test: /\.js$/,
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    include: [resolve('src'), resolve('test'), resolve('node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client'), resolve('node_modules/v-calendar')]
  },
```